# round-robin in bash script

Tags: shell-script, algorithms, round-robin

i have this task to do, but im actually stuck with this round-robin algorithm, here's the details input file there are 3 process A, B and C second column is the arrival time third column is nut value

```
A 1 2
B 2 3
C 0 4
```

i understand the idea that process with AT=0 status should be R=running then the next process with AT status should present as W=waiting after the process has reached the nut value, for ex 4 R status next seq should be F=finished output like

```
  A B C
0 - - R
1 W - R
2 R W W
3 W W R
4 W R W
5 R W W
6 F W R
7 F R F
8 F R F
9 F F F
```

i tired to use the same idea of first come first serve but it's different as here we have to use the round robin algorithm and i didn't saw it before in bash if just someone give me the idea and i will try to continue till the end

```
nut value in the third column mean for ex first process A =2
so it must have two running status then it be finished
process C=4, must have 4 running status then finished and so on
the algorithm is round-robin i found this is the suitable one as the running status changes each line between the processes
```

yes each time only one running status and the other either not arrived yet or in waiting status

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify a bit. What is "for ex 4 R status"? Are you trying to say "for example, for `R` status?" or is `4 R` some other status? Or did you mean "for example, if I have 4 lines with `R` status"?  Also, please add a clear input example and the exact output you expect from that example.

Comment: yes i mean by 4 R status, if we talk about for ex third line in the input file, C 0 4, so the process id is C and the arrival time is 0 and nut is 4, it means after it have 4 running status (R) the next line is has to be finished status (F)

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and clarify. I still don't know if you mean four separate `R`, or one status with the value `4 R`.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a university/recruitment assignment, so I choose to provide insight and crumbs rather than a script.

AFAICT from the example case, the `id_nut` (third column) is what round-robin accounts for iteration, with decreasing order in this case to be specific. However, for efficiency you should not allocate time for non-existing/ non-arrived nut instances (e.g. A, B, C); thus adding nuts only after they arrived to the party. I specifically did not use word queue, because they are ordered by `id_nut` not time of arrival.

So the arrival log (the first table) is there for you to test your logic by simulating such a scenario. Most probably there will be other tests unbeknown to you.

1. Find a way to trigger arrivals at those specific points in time. Try `awk` for sorting them by time column first. Use a queue maybe.
2. Keep a priority `sort`'ed list of arrived nuts. Could be a multi-line string or array.
3. Loop over desired period of time, `seq` to the rescue for creating a range.
4. Of course you would need to decide which nut to trigger next based on your current state before next iteration. However, how would you know some nut was not on the list in last iteration, yet is in the current iteration?

Hopefully, these tips should suffice.

**Edit:** I was mistaken by saying the execution order is by `id_nut` (third column), as that column is said to be `num_run_left` (number of remaining steps/allocations to run the process). Then this is indeed an alphabetically decreasing round-robin. Tweak the tips above accordingly and store `num_run_left` per nut while iterating.

Also, maybe share your solution on some platform if not here. Mind that tools like Turnitin can claim plagiarism, better to share after submitting.